# Convert string to italics xaml

Tags: xaml

My xaml code looks as below :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

 <system:String x:Key="AppName">abcd</system:String>
 <system:String x:Key="btn_Login_Text">Log ind…</system:String>
 <system.....
 <system....
</ResourceDictionary>
```

---

How do i convert just the string abcd to italics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a `System.String`, It does not have any style.

Change the `FontStyle` of the `TextBlock` or `TextBox` where you are using this.

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource AppName}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
```